# Oracle Apex Interactive grid - Issue setting column value with JavaSript

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I got an Interactive grid with a Switch column ('Yes'/'No').
I have a requirement that only one record in the grid should have a Switch column value equals to ‘Yes’ ('Y').

If user enters a new row, and there is already a row in the grid with Switch column equals to “Y”, then the new row's value of the Switch column should be set to ‘No’ ('N').

I am looping through the Interactive grid to get values of the Switch column, to determine if any value equals to ‘Y".
I've got the following function, which suppose to return true if 'Y' is found:

```
function mainInd (gridId, colName) {
//Get the Interactive grid widget instance
  var ig$   = apex.region(gridId).widget();
  var model = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView").model;
  var colValue;
 //Loop through the records in the interactive grid
   ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model.forEach(function(record) {
     console.log('***************mainInd() - record: ' + record );
   colValue = model.getValue(record,colName).v;
     console.log('***************mainInd() - colValue: ' + colValue );
   return Boolean(colValue === 'Y');
   //return colValue === 'Y'; //did not work either
 });
}
```

However the function does not return the boolean.

I am using this function in a Row Initialization DA of the Interactive grid:

```
var model = this.data.model,
    rec   = this.data.record,
    meta  = model.getRecordMetadata(this.data.recordId);
 if ( meta.inserted )
 {
  if ( mainInd("BP","MAIN_BUYER_IND") ){
      console.log('**************Row Init DA - expected true: ' + mainInd("BP","MAIN_BUYER_IND") );
     model.setValue(rec,"MAIN_BUYER_IND", {d:"No", v:"N"});
    } else {
      console.log('**************Row Init DA - expected false: ' + mainInd("BP","MAIN_BUYER_IND") );
     model.setValue(rec,"MAIN_BUYER_IND", {d:"Yes", v:"Y"});
   }
}
```

I am not getting proper true or false boolean. All I'm getting in the console is ‘undefined’. And therefore the logic does not work as expected.
I also tried:

```
 function mainInd (gridId, colName) {
 //Get the interactive grid widget instance
   var ig$   = apex.region(gridId).widget();
   var model = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView").model;
   var colValue;
  //Loop through the records in the interactive grid
    ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model.forEach(function(record) {
      console.log('***************mainInd() - record: ' + record );
    colValue = model.getValue(record,colName).v;
    if (colValue === 'Y') {
      console.log('***************mainInd() - colValue: ' + colValue );
      return true;
    }
   return false;
  });
}
```

It did not work either.

Can you please check the code and let me know what is the issue with it?

Here is the demo if you want to see the console:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=108817:23:112338007040585::::P23_CUSTOMER_ID:1

User: guest
Passw: demo2023

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that you can't return anything from forEach loop, you can only set a value in a loop. You have to return a value outside of a loop.
Here is my final function code that works fine:

```
function mainInd (gridId, colName) {
 // Get the interactive grid widget instance
 var ig$     = apex.region(gridId).widget();
 var view    = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");  
 var model   = ig$.data.model;   
 var colValue;
 var boolean = false;    
    
 // Loop through all records in the interactive grid
 ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model.forEach(function(record) {
      console.log('***************mainInd() - record: ' + record );  
     colValue = model.getValue(record,colName).v;   
  if (colValue === 'Y') {
     boolean = true;
      console.log('***************mainInd() - colValue: ' + colValue );
    }     
  });   
  return boolean;
}
```